# From the point of view of utilitarianism, should we consider everyone as immoral? Since no one meets the moral standards of utilitarianism

Tags: ethics, utilitarianism

I say that no one meets the moral standards of utilitarianism because a faithful adherence to the utilitarian criteria would require you to give your resources until you lower your standard of living to that of the most needy people that you could help, since these people need food and medicine more than you need your luxuries.

Comment: Your approach eventually led to what's now called "effective altruism." For a good starting point, see [Famine, Affluence, & Morality (Singer 1971)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Famine,_Affluence,_and_Morality).

Comment: "*That's right, Five, always put the blame on others.*"

Comment: There are many variations on the utilitarian theme, among which is the idea that subjective and objective rightness diverge: we are only to be judged for doing our best to figure out what the most good is in a given case, not for trying to decide the good of the whole world once and for all. A more troublesome issue has turned out to be that, as long as there is even a small amount of good on every given day, the sum of good for all time is the same as if there had been a slightly larger amount per day.

Comment: So rather than everyone being immoral, it seems as though it would turn out that everyone is always as moral as is needed, even when we commit mass murder.

Comment: Not meeting moral standards is not the test for being immoral. The standards are aspirational maxims intentionally set up to not be met. What moral people are expected to do is follow some minimal rules, *strive* to do more, and make amends when they fall short. Utilitarianism is not distinguished in this regard. No one meets the moral standards of Christianity either, not even saints. This is why Christians emphasize that all humans are sinners and can only be redeemed through God's forgiveness and grace. But they should seek those to get them.

Comment: So at what point do we consider effort enough?
Are those who don't donate to charity not trying hard enough? What determines that someone is trying hard?